# Nothing happens when using 3DPrint

Tags: 3d-printing

I have selected my mesh (repetier says it is not manifold) and try to active the 3Dprint analysis.

I tap space and type 3DPrint. I have tried using Check all, Check solid and Info area. Nothing happens. I'm not sure what should happen.

Comment: -1, The addon's `Location:` specifies the `3D View > Toolbar`.

Comment: Probably most questions here can be answered by finding the correct documentation elsewhere. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use the Check All button (or any other test) in the Print3D panel of the toolbar (visible by pressing <kbd>T</kbd>) you will see a list at the bottom of the panel listing the number of affected parts for each test.

While in edit mode this list becomes buttons for any items that exist. Clicking a button will select the particular areas.

[image]

The coloured areas you see in the above image are from another related feature called Mesh Analysis, this feature highlights the affected areas and can be activated in edit mode from the properties panel (visible by pressing <kbd>N</kbd>).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, now that I know how it works it works well. But I still think the GUI need polishing. :)

Comment: Still a rather new feature so I would expect improvements to keep happening for some time yet.